# Expandable ListView duplicates child data into parent data

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm using a expandable listview to populate categories data. Few categories have sub categories while some don't have. The parent categories list is displayed perfectly. The problem lies in sub categories. The data added is correct but while rendering the data in adapter, the subcategories in groupId 1 are added to other groupId's which have subcategories due to which the groupId subcategories are displayed in other categories.

The below code is in activity when the data is set to the HashMap.

```
private List<String> listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild = new 
HashMap<String, List<String>>();
private List<String> childValues = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void categoriesFetched(List<ArticleCategory> categories) {
    listDataHeader.clear();
    listDataChild.clear();
    childValues.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
        if (categories.get(i).getSub_categories().size() > 0) {
            childValues = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < categories.get(i).getSub_categories().size(); j++) {
                childValues.add(categories.get(i).getSub_categories().get(j).getValue());
            }
            listDataChild.put(categories.get(i).getValue(), childValues);
        } else {
            listDataChild.put(categories.get(i).getValue(), new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        listDataHeader.add(categories.get(i).getValue());
    }
    articlesCategoryAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The below code snippet is the adapter class when the view is rendered.

```
  public class ArticlesCategoryAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild = new HashMap<>();

public ArticlesCategoryAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_category_child, null);
        String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
        AppCompatTextView txtListChild = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubCategoryName);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_category_group, null);
        AppCompatTextView lblListHeader = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMainCategoryName);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Have you logged the data that your are using in your Exp. List??

Comment: yes , and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views are not set correctly when recycled. Try this:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_category_child, null);
    }
    AppCompatTextView txtListChild = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtSubCategoryName);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_category_group, null);
    }
    AppCompatTextView lblListHeader = (AppCompatTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMainCategoryName);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! This helps :)